# Comparing two semantics, equivalent in the global sense, not in the local sense?

Tags: logic, model-theory, proof-theory

I am working on a project that involves a deductive system $\vdash$, with two model-theoretic semantics $\models_A$ and $\models_B$, for which $\vdash$ is sound and complete. That is,

$\Gamma \vdash \phi$ iff $\Gamma \models_A \phi $ iff $\Gamma \models_B \phi$.

Here, $\Gamma\models_A \phi$ means the standard: for all $A$ models $*$, if for all $\gamma\in \Gamma$, $\gamma^*$ is true in the model $*$, then $\phi^*$ is true in the model $*$, and similarly for $B$.

Yet, $\models_A$ and $\models_B$ are not equivalent. For every $A$ model $*$ there exists a $B$ model $\circ$ that validates exactly the same formulas, but the reverse is not true. For example, either $*\models_A \phi$ or $*\models_A \neg \phi$, for any $A$ model $*$.  But there are $B$ models $\circ$ such that $\circ\not\models_B \phi$ and $\circ\not\models_B \neg \phi$.

My question is, what is this phenomenon called?

Comment: Note: it may be better to phrase the criterion as "if for all $\gamma \in \Gamma$, $\gamma^*$ is true in the model $*$, then $\phi^*$ is true in the model $*$." This eliminates the need to assume the law of excluded middle in the metatheory. Of course, if you're working in the usual metatheory (ZFC) then this is irrelevant, but it's always good practice to get results that apply as broadly as possible.

Comment: Edited according to Mark Saving's suggestion.